# Navbar colapse após seleção?

Tags: jquery, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Quando se usa o `navbar` do bootstrap em um celular ele não retornar ao normal após clicar em opção do *menu*.

No exemplo a seguir a barra de navegação é substituída por um botão no canto superior direito. Somente quando este botão é clicado o menu some. Como faço para ele fechar após a seleção de algum item do navbar?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você deseja "colapsar" o menu após a seleção de algum item, quando o layout estiver em um dispositivo menor.

Basta você adicionar o seguinte jquery:

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function(){
    $('.btn-navbar').click(); //bootstrap 2.x
    $('.navbar-toggle').click() //bootstrap 3.x
});
```

## Veja funcionando aqui.

```js
$('.nav a').on('click', function(){
    $('.navbar-toggle').click();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito grato, então a única mudança foi o javascript?

Comment: @itasouza eu deixei um exemplo do Jquery acima pra quem usa a versão 2 e pra quem usa a versão 3.

Comment: Quando eu testei o código javascript observei que fica um efeito estanho no site aberto no computador, apenas no celular funciona sem este feito estranho, então eu vou precisar executar o jascript apenas quando for um celular,vou abri uma nova questão sobre isso

Comment: @itasouza faz um `if` verificando se é mobile. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200501/executar-javascript-apenas-quando-acessar-o-site-de-um-celular

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde meu amigo, primeiramente obrigado ao marconi pelo seu tempo e ajuda, gostaria de deixar aqui uma pequena atualização e correção ao favor que ele nos fez. **O .nav n é classe, então é $('nav a')** ....    e a classe a ser clicada falta um R, **é toggleR**. Abaixo umas coisas q podem estar interferindo além do código.

*1- Como já li por aí, tem gente q pode ter posto para carregar 2 vezes o bootstrap.js e o jquery.js

2- Inserir esse script SOMENTE DEPOIS de ter chamado o script jquery.js, se inserir antes ele n vai ter carregado o jquery e logo n vai processar certo, então carrega o jquery antes, em seguida carrega o bloco("função") q usa ele.*

abaixo o código atualizado/corrigido seguindo o postado acima:

```
$('nav a').on('click', function(){
   $('.navbar-toggler').click();
});
```

Porém, quando vai pro desktop ele recebe esse bloco também e fica ruim. Para evitar isso fiz uma media query para telas menores que tablet, se quiser somente no mobile trocar o 768 por 576.

Abaixo o código com media query, e para o meu projeto que tem o meu logo como botão home, estava dando problema, pois o bloco pediu tudo que for link(a) na nav, e ele seguiu isso p esse logo/botão home, então eu queria voltar para home, clicava nele e ele abria o menu, para corrigir isso chamei a classe .navbar-nav e somente o que for link(a) dentro dela) :

```
x = window.screen.width;
if(x <= 768){
  $('.navbar-nav a').on('click', function(){
      $('.navbar-toggler').click();
  });
}
```

Meu primeiro post aqui, espero que ajude alguém, afinal ajudando que a gente aprende mais.
Uma abraço!