# Executar javascript apenas quando acessar o site de um celular

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Eu observei que o menu do bootstraps não fecha após a seleção de uma opção quando estar usando um celular, então eu quero executar apenas se estiver em um celular, estou fazendo desta forma, seria o correto? Agradeço

```
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad|android)/);

        if (agentID) {
             alert('você está utilizando um celular');

            $('.nav a').on('click', function(){
                //$('.btn-navbar').click(); //bootstrap 2.x
                $('.navbar-toggle').click() //bootstrap 3.x
            }); 

        } else {
           alert('você está em um computador');
      }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

**NÃO.**

Seu site vai funcionar hoje para uma quantidade específica de dispositivos móveis. Provavelmente vai atender a 95% dos casos. Mas tem dois problemas:

- Problema menor: vai deixar de fora alguns poucos dispositivos. Tudo bem, não tem muita gente mesmo que navega usando um Playstation Vita ou um N95 (sim, a Nokia tem smartphones que não são Android), mas ainda assim isso é deselegante;
- Problema maior: daqui a um tempo surgem novos dispositivos que possuem novas identificações de *user agent* e seu site não estará pronto pra eles. Pior, os navegadores atuais podem mudar seus identificadores em uma atualização. Daí seu site para de funcionar da noite pro dia.

Vou repetir aqui o que eu já falei em outra pergunta mais específica:

**[NÃO USE USERAGENT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195182/1658)**

Se você não quer que alguma coisa funcione em dispositivos móveis, detectar o tamanho da tela é menos deselegante do que ler *useragent*. Mas se você quiser mesmo saber se um script que você vai rodar **é suportado pelo navegador alvo -
 o que é muito mais preciso do que apenas verificar qual é o navegador** - utilize alguma biblioteca como o Modernizr.

Pode ser que alguma coisa do bootstrap funcione em um modelo de Android e não funcione em outro. Se tudo que você faz para determinar se serve ou não esse conteúdo é verificar se o usuário navega com o Chrome para Android, você está fazendo isso muito errado.

Sério gente, parem de chavear funcionalidade pela *user agent* do navegador porque isso é mais feio do que bater na própria mãe.

Answer (score -1):

Sim, esta é uma boa maneira pois não depende do tamanho da tela, mas creio que você possa usar diretamente na condição sem ter que gerar uma variável.

```
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

        if (deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad|android)/)) {
             alert('você está utilizando um celular');

            $('.nav a').on('click', function(){
                //$('.btn-navbar').click(); //bootstrap 2.x
                $('.navbar-toggle').click() //bootstrap 3.x
            }); 

        } else {
           alert('você está em um computador');
      }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: valeu! agradeço a ajuda

Answer (score -1):

Acho que da pra fazer assim também, caso queira usar menos código:

```
if(/Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {

}
```